error NaN cuando se intenta imprimir una string extraida de un array
//Se intenta imprimir un index random de un array pero da como resultado NaN

let nombres = [];

let entrada= prompt("Ingresa el nombre");

while(entrada){
    entrada= prompt("Ingresa el nombre");
    nombres.push(entrada);

}

conteo=Math.floor(Math.random() * nombres);

String(conteo);

console.log(` ${conteo}  debe de pagar la cuenta`);


Nombres es un array, no un número de ahí Nan (Not A Number). Tu código debería ser Math.floor(Math.random() * nombres.length); si lo que intentas es usar el tamaño del arreglo.

No habia analizado el orden de las instrucciones, gracias por la observacion.

Hay varios problemas con tu código:

No insertas el primer nombre ingresado al arreglo, y en cambio, insertas la cadena vacía cuándo el usuario solo presiona enter, que es la condición de salida. Para resolverlo, hay que darle vuelta a las instrucciones dentro del primer while. Analízalo y el código se explicará por sí solo.

el NaN (Not a Number) proviene de la multiplicación:
 Math.random() * nombres

pues nombres no es un número (es un arreglo).

Puedes obtener una posición aleatoria dentro del arreglo con el número de elementos del arreglo, que se obtiene con la propiedad length, así:
 Math.random() * nombres.length


La sentencia String(conteo); es superflúa, pues no almacenas el resultado en ningún lugar, se puede eliminar completamente.

No tiene sentido imprimir el índice, es poco amigable al usuario. Es mejor imprimir el nombre que corresponde a ese índice.


Corrigiendo estas cosas, quedaría algo como:


let nombres = [];
let entrada= prompt("Ingresa el nombre");
while(entrada) {
  nombres.push(entrada);
  entrada= prompt("Ingresa el nombre");
}
let indicePagador = Math.floor(Math.random() * nombres.length);
let pagador = nombres[indicePagador];
console.log(`${pagador} debe de pagar la cuenta`);




no estas escribiendo bien la sintaxis de lo que quieres hacer. A demás el bucle lo tienes de manera infinita sin escribirle bien la sintaxis y puesto de manera infinita donde no llegaría a la variable pagador nunca.


let nombres = [];
let entrada = "";

for ( let n = 1; n <= 5; n++){
  entrada = prompt("Ingresa el nombre", "");
  nombres.push(entrada);
}
let indicePagador = Math.floor(Math.random() * nombres.length);
let pagador = nombres[indicePagador];
console.log(pagador);



Si lo pones con un ciclo for cuentas las veces que se repite que en mi caso e puesto 5
